# Asking polite question in email

Tags: email

I want to asking question to my collegeous in email; the situation are there is a "marketing budget" and the second parties told me they have an event with embassy i confuse are they purpose to using their marketing budget or they just as a bridge to give me a project, so the question are; is it this event using the existing budget? Or this is a paid event? . Please advise thank you

Answer (score 2):

"Please kindly clarify the information about the event so I can plan for it: Is the event one for which I should make payment? (If so, please send me the information.) Or were you planning on using your marketing budget to cover the event?" Alternatively, for the last sentence: "Or will attending be coming out of your marketing budget?"  Does something like this help?